# React Table - types of property 'accessor' are incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table-v7

I am trying out react-table in create-react-app project (version `^7.0.25`). I am using the exact example from their quick start [documentation](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/quick-start). However, I am getting a type error between the accessor and data columns. below is my code,

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Solution } from '../../../Models/SolutionModel';
import {useTable} from 'react-table'

interface ICompareTableComponentProps {
  Solutions : Solution[]
}

const CompareTableComponent: React.FunctionComponent<ICompareTableComponentProps> = (props) => {
    
    const data = React.useMemo(
      () => [
        {
          col1: 'Hello',
          col2: 'World',
        },
        {
          col1: 'react-table',
          col2: 'rocks',
        },
        {
          col1: 'whatever',
          col2: 'you want',
        },
      ],
      []
    )
  
    const columns = React.useMemo(
      () => [
        {
          Header: 'Column 1',
          accessor: 'col1', // accessor is the "key" in the data
        },
        {
          Header: 'Column 2',
          accessor: 'col2',
        },
      ],
      []
    )
  
    const {
      getTableProps,
      getTableBodyProps,
      headerGroups,
      rows,
      prepareRow,
    } = useTable({ columns, data })
  
    return (
      <table {...getTableProps()} style={{ border: 'solid 1px blue' }}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th
                  {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                  style={{
                    borderBottom: 'solid 3px red',
                    background: 'aliceblue',
                    color: 'black',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                  }}
                >
                  {column.render('Header')}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map(row => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return (
                    <td
                      {...cell.getCellProps()}
                      style={{
                        padding: '10px',
                        border: 'solid 1px gray',
                        background: 'papayawhip',
                      }}
                    >
                      {cell.render('Cell')}
                    </td>
                  )
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
          
};
export default CompareTableComponent;
```

Below is my the full error,

```
Type '{ Header: string; accessor: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Column<{ col1: string; col2: string; }>[]'.
  Type '{ Header: string; accessor: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Column<{ col1: string; col2: string; }>'.
    Type '{ Header: string; accessor: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ColumnInterface<{ col1: string; col2: string; }> & { accessor: "col2"; } & ColumnInterfaceBasedOnValue<{ col1: string; col2: string; }, string>'.
      Type '{ Header: string; accessor: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ accessor: "col2"; }'.
        Types of property 'accessor' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"col2"'.  TS2322
```

I have tried with converting the columns into objects but no luck.

```
{
    col1: 'react-table' as any,
    col2: 'rocks' as any,
}
```

I am sure I am overlooking something very trivial but cannot seem to find the issue. Any help on this will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this issue?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem here but when using string column accessors you should put `as const` at the end:
`accessor: 'col1'` -> `accessor: 'col1' as const`

Answer (score 8):

your `useMemo` lacks typing

```js
const columns = useMemo<Column<{col1: string}>[]>(() => [
  {
    col1: 'hello world',
  },
], [])
```

Comment: No, that doesn't fix the issue.

 ```Type '{ col1: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Column<{ col1: string; }>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'col1' does not exist in type 'Column<{ col1: string; }>'.```

Comment: @ElioBriceño You would need to type the memo as an _array_ of columns: 
`useMemo<Column<{col1: string}>[ ]>`

Answer (score 2):

Check this topic here: https://github.com/ggascoigne/react-table-example/issues/3

Basically you need to define:

```js
const columns: Array<Column<{ col1: string; col2: string }>> = useMemo(
```

.. or use an interface for the data rows:

```js
const columns: Array<Column<DataInterface>> = ...
```

Comment: ```interface Data { name: string }```  ```const column: Column<Data> = { accessor: 'name' }```
Shouldn't that work? TS2322: Type '"name"' is not assignable to type 'Accessor<Data> | (Accessor<Data> & "name") | undefined'.

Answer (score 1):

Things which worked for me:

- Created an interface

  ```
  interface Data {
   id: number;
   first_name: string;
   last_name: string;
   email: string;
   date_of_birth: string;
   age: number;
   country: string;
   phone: string
  }
  ```
- Define columns as follows:

  ```
  const columns = React.useMemo<Column<Data>[]>(
   () => [
       { Header: "ID", accessor: "id" },
       { Header: "First name", accessor: "first_name" },
       { Header: "Last name", accessor: "last_name" },
       { Header: "Email", accessor: "email" },
       { Header: "Date of Birth", accessor: "date_of_birth" },
       { Header: "Age", accessor: "age" },
       { Header: "Country", accessor: "country" },
       { Header: "Phone", accessor: "phone" },
   ],
   []
  ```

  );

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I took to solve this:

### 1. Define table data interface

```js
interface ITableData {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  email: string;
  date_of_birth: string;
  age: number;
  country: string;
  phone: string;
}
```

### 2. Define generic type for useMemo on `columns`

```js
import { Column } from "react-table";

const columns = useMemo<readonly Column<ITableData>[]>(() => COLUMNS, []);
```

### 3. cast `accessor` as const

```js
const COLUMNS = [
  {
    Header: "ID",
    accessor: "id" as const
  },
  {
    Header: "First Name",
    accessor: "first_name" as const
  },
  {
    Header: "Last Name",
    accessor: "last_name" as const
  },
  {
    Header: "Email",
    accessor: "email" as const
  },
  {
    Header: "Date Of Birth",
    accessor: "date_of_birth" as const
  },
  {
    Header: "Age",
    accessor: "age" as const
  },
  {
    Header: "Country",
    accessor: "country" as const
  },
  {
    Header: "Phone",
    accessor: "phone" as const
  },
]


export default COLUMNS;
```

My data looks like this:

```json
[
{"id":1,"first_name":"Torie","last_name":"Rustman","email":"trustman0@amazon.co.uk","date_of_birth":"1979-11-16T23:04:32Z","age":45,"country":"Argentina","phone":"6844103517"},
...
]
```